# What is the isalpha() equivalent in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a field in **pymongo** by the name "**Processed_Email_Body**". How do I check if it contains any letters or not, basically my objective is to find the count of empty processed email bodies, as the empty ones only contain dots and nothing else. So if the body does not have any letters, I will keep incrementing the count.

As of now I am stuck here:

```
iid = 11651704
database_69.user_emails.find({"Message_Id": iid, "Processing_Variables": {"Processed_Email_Body": }})
```

Any ideas to proceed further?

Comment: How about using `"$regex"`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I tried that but it is not working. Also, how do I use $regex and check if the body has only dots and no other alphabets?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to return docs with **only** `.` (one or more) in `"Processing_Variables.Processed_Email_Body"`.  You can provide more fields in the filter if you want (e.g., `"Message_Id"`).  Also note that you may need to "escape" the `.` in the `"$regex"` differently in Python.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "Processing_Variables.Processed_Email_Body": {
    "$regex": "^\\.+$",
    "$options": "m"
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Db_wbyulfg1).

Here's a way to get the "count of empty processed email bodies".

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "Processing_Variables.Processed_Email_Body": {
        "$regex": "^\\.+$",
        "$options": "m"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "emptyBodiesCount"
  }
])
```

Try this on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P1YCc2Cfk3v).